# Why are unilateral Laplace transforms suitable for causal systems and bilateral aren't?

Tags: fourier-transform

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform#Causality

The above section says that bilateral transforms will not necessarily make sense for causal systems. In the course of advanced engineering mathematics our instructor told us that's because the unilateral version is integrated over time $t=0$ to $t= ∞$.

But that's more like a memory aid than a reason. There's no reason why, when it comes to real systems, I can integrate from time $t=0$ to $t= ∞$, but can't for time $t=-∞$ to $t= ∞$. The relation this has to causality isn't obvious. I was not able to find a proof or a more solid grounding for this using Google.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148684/2451

Answer (score 1):

Usually, what you are taking the Laplace transform of, is the system response, $h(t)$, e.g. system's response to a delta input, $\delta(t)$. If system's delta response is nonzero at $t<0$ it would mean the system had been anticipating your delta input at $t=0$ and already started responding, which is non-causal. Therefore a causal system must have $h(t)$ such that $h(t)=0$ for $t<0$. If you are using a unilateral Laplace transform it automatically makes sure that you are at least ignoring the non-causal part ($t<0$) of $h(t)$. So really, you should make sure that you have modeled your system correctly, so that it is causal at the first place and not rely on the kind of Laplace transform you are using. For example, $h(t)=\exp(-at)u(t)$ is a causal response, where $u(t)$ is Heaviside's step function, but $h(t)=\exp(-at)u(t+1)$ is not.